# Issue in uploading build with Notification Content and Notification Service extension

Tags: ios, notifications, certificate, xcode11

I am using XCode 11.2.1 Version. I have Notification Content and Notification Service extension in my app.
I have created separate App store profile for extensions and for project. I have different App IDs too.
When I archive project with "Automatically manage signing" ,IPA got created successfully but when I am using app store certificate I am getting error or "symbols tool failed" and sometimes "Invalid Bundle Structure".

I am sharing some screenshots for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its been 3 days I am trying to create build. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Might be a framework linker issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209404/2323806

Comment: Already checked